# LibNet read ARP response?

Tags: c++, c, networking, arp, libnet

Is it possible to read ARP responses with Libnet? I'm looking specifically for a cross-platform library to read ARP sockets written in C/C++ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libnet` is a library for portable packet construction and injection. The consumption and decapsulation has to be done elsewhere. I suggest [`libtrace`](http://research.wand.net.nz/software/libtrace.php) or [`libpcap`](http://www.tcpdump.org/) to help with that business.

`libnet` is primarily useful if you want to build and inject ARP packets. To see how this is done, have a look at [some sample ARP code](https://github.com/mschiffm/libnet-1/blob/master/libnet/sample/arp-new.c). Additionally, once packets are snarfed from the wire/air/file, `libnet` can be helpful for its rolodex of portable packet header definitions. In your case, you'd want to have a look at [`struct libnet_arp_hdr`](https://github.com/mschiffm/libnet-1/blob/master/libnet/include/libnet/libnet-headers.h#L196). You can cast your captured packet into an ARP header by doing something like:

```
    ...
    struct libnet_arp_hdr *arp_h;

    buf = capturepacket();
    ...
    arp_h = (struct libnet_arp_hdr *)buf + LIBNET_ETH_H;
    ...
    switch (arp_h->ar_op)
    {
        case ARPOP_REQUEST:
            ...
```